# Flutter: Exception Error Type ((type '(Brand) => int' is not a subtype of type '((dynamic) => Comparable<dynamic>)?')

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using Generic Class to achieve my logic , but i am facing this error

> ```
> _TypeError (type '(Brand) => int' is not a subtype of type '((dynamic) => Comparable<dynamic>)?')
> ```

### Code:

**Generic Class:**

```
class DataColumnsSorter<T, R> {
  DataColumnsSorter(
      {required this.isNumeric,
      required this.type,
      required this.columnName,
      required this.onSort});
  bool isNumeric;
  dynamic type;
  String columnName;
  Comparable<R> Function(T)? onSort;
}
```

**Object:**
*Brand is model*

```
final sorter = DataColumnsSorter<Brand,num>(
          columnName: 'id',
          isNumeric: true,
          onSort: (brand) => brand.id ?? 0, <---- Problem starts here
          type: 0),
```

**Implementation:**

```
///Create a column to PaginatedDataTable 
DataColumn(
            label: Text(sorter.columnName),
            // tooltip: sorter.columnName,
            numeric: sorter.isNumeric,
            onSort: (colIndex, asc) {
                    _sort(sorter.onSort!, colIndex, asc, paginationData, bloc); <--- Throw exception in this line
                  });




void _sort(
    Comparable Function(dynamic d) getField,
    int colIndex,
    bool asc,
    BlocPaginationData paginationData,
    BlocDataTableCubit bloc,
  ) {
    paginationData.sort(getField, asc);
    bloc.setAsc = asc;
    bloc.setSortColumnIndex = colIndex;
  }




///Inside paginationData<Brand> extends DataTableSource
void paginationData.sort(Comparable Function(T d) getField, bool asc) {
    bloc.data.sort((a, b) {
      final aValue = getField(a);
      final bValue = getField(b);
      return asc
          ? Comparable.compare(aValue, bValue)
          : Comparable.compare(bValue, aValue);
    });

    notifyListeners();
  }
```

Can i find a possible way to pass generic function to another generic function ?
You see my code is passing generic function (sorter.onSort) to (_sort) then to (paginationData.sort()).

Comment: I'm confused; your question title refers to "'int' isn't a 'Comparable<int>'", but that's not the error message you're receiving.

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from this call

```
_sort(sorter.onSort!, colIndex, asc, paginationData, bloc);
```

According to your code, the `_sort` method expects the following parameters:

```
void _sort(
    Comparable Function(dynamic d) getField,
    ...
) {}
```

But the `sorter.onSort!` is of type `int Function(Brand)` and not `Comparable Function(dynamic d)`. To make it more clear: One function expects the input to be of type `Brand`and the other expects it to be of type `dynamic`. That is not compatible!

You will have to rewrite parts of your code to make this sorting functions compatible. Without more background, this is hard to answer from the outside

Comment: Can i find a possible way to pass generic function to another generic function ?